# Using boost c++ to read a serial port, how should I decode the data?

Tags: c++, boost, serial-port

I am trying to create a simple app that reads data from a serial port. I have the structure of the data, it is as follows:

```
Byte Function   Format      Example Hex 
0    Header     ASCII Char  I       49  
1   Header      ASCII Char  W       57  
2   Header      ASCII Char  A       41  
3   Header      ASCII Char  P       50  
4   Header      ASCII Char  I       49  
5   Header      ASCII Char  x       78  
6   Version     uint8_t 1   1   
7   Pan         int32_t     0A  
8   Pan         int32_t     0B  
9   Pan         int32_t     0C  
10  Pan         int32_t 168496141   0D  
11  Tilt        int32_t     0A  
12  Tilt        int32_t     0B  
13  Tilt        int32_t     0C  
14  Tilt        int32_t 168496141   0D  
15  Roll        int32_t     0A  
16  Roll        int32_t     0B  
17  Roll        int32_t     0C  
18  Roll        int32_t 168496141   0D  
19  Jog A       int32_t     0A  
20  Jog A       int32_t     0B  
21  Jog A       int32_t     0C  
22  Jog A       int32_t 168496141   0D  
23  Jog B       int32_t     0A  
24  Jog B       int32_t     0B  
25  Jog B       int32_t     0C  
26  Jog B       int32_t 168496141   0D  
27  Focus       uint16_t            0A  
28  Focus       uint16_t    2571    0B  
29  Iris        uint16_t            0A  
30  Iris        uint16_t    2571    0B  
31  Zoom        uint16_t            0A  
32  Zoom        uint16_t    2571    0B  
33  To One      uint8_t (blip)  10  0A  
34  Reverse     uint8_t (blip)  10  0A  
35  Pause       uint8_t (blip)  10  0A  
36  Forward     uint8_t (blip)  10  0A  
37  Reserved                
38  Reserved                
39  Reserved                
40  Reserved                
41  Reserved                
42  Reserved                
43  Reserved                
44  Reserved                
45  Checksum    CheckSum8 Modulo 256            
46  Footer      ASCII Char  ;     3B    
47  Footer      ASCII Char  !     21    
48  Footer      ASCII Char  ;     3B
```

The data is: UART: 921600 Baud, 8N2, Big-Endian

I am opening the port like this, and reading data:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp> 
using namespace std;
using namespace boost;


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    asio::io_service io;
    asio::serial_port port(io);

    port.open("COM14");
    port.set_option(asio::serial_port_base::baud_rate(921600));

    char c;
    std::string rsp;
    
    while (c != ';')
    {
        asio::read(port, asio::buffer(&c, 1));
        rsp += c;
    }

    std::cout << rsp << std::endl;

    port.close();

    std::cin.get();
}
```

This gives me the string:

```
IWVPx  :ã                               {;
```

Obviously i am doing this wrong, I think because I am reading the data as `char`.
What is the correct way to read serial port data and convert it to readable data?

Comment: Reading the data as `char` isn't bad. After reading, you should retrieve data from the array of `char`.

Comment: Hi! Can you please explain a little more what you mean? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the structure provided in order to parse the data.  The blank spaces that you're seeing are most likely due to ASCII interpretation of binary data.  The clue that this is binary data is that the writer is specify byte position.  Here's how I would approach parsing this data.

First, create a structure that matches that the data that you are going to parse:

```
struct Data
{
    char header[5];
    uint8_t ver;
    int32_t pan;
    int32_t tilt;
    int32_t roll;
    int32_t joga;
    int32_t jogb;
    uint16_t focus;
    uint16_t iris;
    uint16_t zoom;
    uint8_t toOne;
    uint8_t reverse;
    uint8_t pause;
    uint8_t forward;
    uint8_t reserved[8];
    uint8_t checksum;
    char footer[3];
}__attribute__((packed));
```

Next, read in all data. There's a lot of instrumentation that would go far beyond the scope of describing how to actually parse this data, so I'm going to leave that out.  Here, I'm referring to ways of ensuring that you have proper packet alignment, getting the second semicolon, checking that the size of the data buffer is the same size of the intended structure.  Some of these come into play only when the packets being sent out are sent automatically versus requested.

Once you fill a buffer, ensure that it is the same size as the data structure, it's as simple as:

```
Data data;
memcpy( &data, buffer, sizeof(data) );
```

The data can then be accessed as if it was part of the structure.  Note that this solution assumes that endianness is consistent across machines.  If it is not, you may have to perform some byte reversals.

The end result may look something like this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    asio::io_service io;
    asio::serial_port port(io);

    port.open("COM14");
    port.set_option(asio::serial_port_base::baud_rate(921600));
        
    uint8_t obuf[256]; // arbitrary size, larger than largest expected buffer   

    // perform packet alignment here

    asio::read(port, asio::buffer(obuf, sizeof(Data)));

    Data d = {};
    memcpy( &d, obuf, sizeof(d) );

    // if your endianness is different than the data sent, fix it here.

    std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Great answer. In my question i am reading chars into a string, should that be a char array instead to use with your code? What would that look like? Thanks again

Comment: Yes, you could use a uint8_t or char buffer to do this.  My original answer was hastily written.  I'll expand upon it.

Comment: Thank you. visual studio is complaing about this line: `asio::read(port, asio::buffer(obuf[cnt], 1));`

Comment: `Error (active) E0304 no instance of overloaded function "boost::asio::buffer" matches the argument list `

Comment: ah, it needs an `&`, perhaps? `asio::read(port, asio::buffer(&obuf[cnt], 1));`

Comment: Running this code with live input is giving strange results! When I print `d.pan` and 'd.roll' in a `while(true)` loop, I get this: `d.pan: 53 d.roll: 0
d.pan: -8388737 d.roll: 53
d.pan: 1611202560 d.roll: -8388737
d.pan: 0 d.roll: 1611202560
d.pan: 419580240 d.roll: 0
d.pan: 557535876 d.roll: 436357456
d.pan: -754974720 d.roll: 557536132
d.pan: 11151872 d.roll: -754974720
d.pan: 889258239 d.roll: 11151872
d.pan: 2142241792 d.roll: 889258239
d.pan: 0 d.roll: 2142241792
d.pan: 5378816 d.roll: 0
d.pan: 1346459465 d.roll: 5378816` The numbers should stay the same, not change per call.

Comment: The expected result would be, for example: `d.pan: 168496141 d.roll: 137877341
d.pan: 168496141 d.roll: 137877341
d.pan: 168496141 d.roll: 137877341
d.pan: 168496141 d.roll: 137877341
d.pan: 168496141 d.roll: 137877341
d.pan: 168496141 d.roll: 137877341` Am i messing up the byte order perhaps?

Comment: How is this data being sent?  Do you have to request it each time or does it come automatically?  If I were troubleshooting this, I would be first printing out the contents of header.

Comment: I noticed this when I was originally observing your question, but there appears to be something wrong with your header.  You have it showing ```IWVPx``` when printed to the screen, however I would have expected ```IWAPIx```.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220815/discussion-between-alex-baum-and-anti).

Comment: Note that all of this makes unstated assumptions about endianness. Specifically, it can only work if the "native" endianness of the receiving host machine matches the endianness documented by the wire protocol.

Comment: @sehe I stated in the solution that a check of the endianness may be required after the data is gathered.  The endianness of the data should not affect the order in which the structures data is received, only the order of the bytes within the data.

Comment: @AlexBaum Good point. I jumped over to the chat end did a search for "endian" - thought it wasn't mentioned. Good job - you already had my +1